Certain sum involving roots of unity like the Lambert series
Let $\ell$ be an odd prime $, \zeta=e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{\ell}}, v \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Then how to prove there exist an integer $N \equiv -v \ (\bmod \ell)$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\zeta^v}{(1-\zeta)^{\ell}}+\frac{\zeta^{2 v}}{\left(1-\zeta^2\right)^{\ell}}+\frac{\zeta^{3v}}{\left(1-\zeta^3\right)^{\ell}}
+\cdots+\frac{\zeta^{(\ell-1)v}}{\left(1-\zeta^{\ell-1}\right)^{\ell}}=\frac{N}{\ell}
\end{aligned} $$ ?
(This is needed for the proof of Lemma 3.7 in  M. Stoll, "On the arithmetic of the curves $y^2=x^{\ell}+A$ II" (2000)
I have checked this for some pair of $\ell=3, 5, 7$.
